# Angular Infinite scroll + mcustomScrollbar for table body

Tags: angularjs, infinite-scroll, fixed-header-tables, mcustomscrollbar

I am trying to implement the Angular JS infinite scroll with fixed header and fixed column. And in the mean time am adding the mcustomscrollbar for scroll features.

I can able to add the scroll functionality outside the table i.e if we add scroll to div its working. But I need to do for table body.

Please find the below link for fiddler, let me know where am doing wrong.

```
''http://jsfiddle.net/jayasant1907/e8nwodx8/
```